# Fetching values from input type=range

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, input-type-range

I have an age range slider with `from` and `to` age. I need to pass the value selected to ng-model, but my ng-model doesn't read the value. Since the slider I created is with jQueryUi.

I need to pass the value selected in as 5-6 in in ng-model. I tried passing values from my jQuery script to ng-model, its not updating.

Need assistance.

HTML:

```
<label for="age">Age:</label>
<input type="text" id="age" ng-model="model.ageRange" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        /*values: [ 0, 100 ],*/
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#age" ).val( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#age" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Comment: jQuery ui widgets has its propper integration with angularjs check this out https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating anything in angular from outside the angular framework, angular will not recognize those changes.So to update your ng-model you need to modify your age range value in $scope.$apply() function provided by angular.See angular docs for more information.